# Integration of pimcore 6.7.1 project in another machine

Tags: php-7.2, pimcore

I've a project developed in PHP >= 7.2 and Pimcore 6.7.1.

I want to run this project on another system but not getting any help.

Pimcore documentation is all about creating new project and then installing pimcore into new project.

anybody can explain how I can run this project?

Comment: You need to be more specific with your problem - aka: what exactly did you try? What kind of (error) messages did you get? Usually, you have to transfer *all* pimcore project files and the database to the new machine. if the database connection credentials changed, you need to change these in the pimcore config, too.

Comment: Thanks for Replying @chluehr . I've project files without vendor folder. When I run 'Composer Install' command using composer 2.2 having PHP 7.4.1 installed on my system it installed required packages. normally we run 'php ./vendor/bin/pimcore-install' command after 'composer install' for a new project. Should I run this command for existing project as well?

Comment: allright, so what you want to achieve is to re-install a Pimcore just from the project files? yes, then you need to run pimcore-install, too. this will give you an "empty" pimcore, though. if you have the class definition files, a classes-rebuild will get you the object classes: https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/current/Development_Documentation/Deployment/Deployment_Tools.html - but not the content!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to **install an existing Pimcore project** then you need:

- checkout or copy its source code
- install pimcore to set configuration of your local DB, something like:

  `php vendor/bin/pimcore-install --mysql-host-socket=db --mysql-username=pimcore --mysql-password=pimcore --mysql-database=pimcore`
- rebuild data-object files and download composer dependancies. In old versions you can execute manually what later became **[./bin/post-merge.sh](https://github.com/pimcore/demo/blob/11.x/bin/post-merge.sh)** See [detailed commands descriptions here](https://pimcore.com/docs/platform/Pimcore/Deployment/Deployment_Tools/).

**If you need to integrate Pimcore to existing non-Pimcore project** then you need:

- install Pimcore in separate folder
- if /admin/ entry-point is conflicting with your existing folders structure then you can change it
- feel free to use Pimcore API and services for cooperation

**If you want to build fresh Pimcore website of newest version, you can simply export/import data from Old Pimcore v.6** to the newest using:

- [DataHub GraphQL](https://pimcore.com/docs/platform/Datahub/GraphQL/) if istalled
- [Data_Importer](https://pimcore.com/docs/platform/Data_Importer/)
- or [CLI SCV export/import scripts](https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/10.6/Development_Documentation/Objects/External_System_Interaction.html)